# Why line lengths are different on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, fonts

Same text looks different on android and ios. As I understand it, the default line heights are different. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```js
import React from "react"
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text } from "react-native"


const Screen = () => {

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <View style={{ width: 200, height: 100, backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        fontFamily: "Comfortaa-Regular",
                        fontSize: 30,
                    }}
                >
                    İİİİ
                </Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default Screen
```

Android

[image]

iOS:

[image]

Comment: Are assets linked properly? In both platforms?

Comment: Yes, I checked. Everything works correctly except the line length.

Comment: Can you try whether this solution works for you? This [method](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7687#issuecomment-220886890) is not recommended but Just give a try.

Comment: Yes it works when I try that. But there is too much text in the app and I don't want to add "paddingTop: Platform.OS =="ios" ? 10 : 0" to all of them. Is there a way I can do this for example by just adding it once in Index.js or App.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm continuing the comment section reply as an answer here.

Yes. You can change props globally based on additional packages. However, what I recommend is to make your own component for Typography and do all the customizations there rather than changing props globally.

Sample Package: https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props

Comment: I added it to index.js as you specified, but there was no change. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbE47.png

Comment: I modified my answer. Please check.